# Create a ListView cell with a structured layout

Tags: android, android-layout

How can I create a `ListView` item cell that is structured like so:

---

Title View----------------------------------------Date View

Subject View------------------------------Category View

---

With the `Title View` aligned to the left and the `Date View` aligned to the right.

The `Subject View` is also aligned to the left and the `Category View` aligned to the right.

The `Subject View` and `Category View` are below the top two views.

I would also like `Title View` to take 66% of the width and `Date View` to take 34% of the width.

`Subject View` should take 50% and `Category View` should take 50%.

This is what I have so far but it displays both `Subject View` and `Category View` strangely:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/background_activated">

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/homework_list_item_titleTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="4dp"
    android:paddingRight="4dp"
    />

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/homework_list_item_dateTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/homework_list_item_titleTextView"
    android:paddingLeft="4dp"
    android:paddingRight="4dp"
    android:paddingTop="4dp"
    />

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/homework_list_item_classTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/homework_list_item_dateTextView"
    android:paddingLeft="4dp"
    android:paddingRight="4dp"
    android:paddingTop="4dp"
    android:text="IB Math HL"
    />

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/homework_list_item_typeTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/homework_list_item_titleTextView"
    android:paddingLeft="4dp"
    android:paddingRight="4dp"
    android:paddingTop="4dp"
    android:text="Homework"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**EDIT:**
Should I alternatively use `LinearLayouts` instead of `RelativeLayout`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I alternatively use `LinearLayout`s instead of `RelativeLayout`?

Taking into consideration that you'd like to divide the views proportionally, it's easier to use `LinearLayout`s and the [`weight`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html#Weight) attribute. Here is the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="100" >

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/homework_list_item_titleTextView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:paddingLeft="4dp"
        android:paddingRight="4dp"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"
        android:layout_weight="66"
        android:text="Title View 66%" />

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/homework_list_item_dateTextView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:paddingLeft="4dp"
        android:paddingRight="4dp"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"
        android:layout_weight="34"
        android:text="Date View 34%" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="100" >

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/homework_list_item_classTextView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:paddingLeft="4dp"
        android:paddingRight="4dp"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:text="Subject View 50%" />

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/homework_list_item_typeTextView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:paddingLeft="4dp"
        android:paddingRight="4dp"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:text="Category View 50%" />

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And here is how it's look like:

[image: screenshot]